# Interpreting the coefficient of determination in an ANOVA

Tags: anova, interpretation, r-squared

I have performed a two way anova and had an R squared of 16%. The following is what I said about the result.

```
16% of the variation in average age can be attributed to weight and height
```

I am not sure if this would be an appropriate statement as this was how I interpreted the R square value in regression and I think it might be different in ANOVA because the model is different.

Can I get a confirmation or correction about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANOVA and linear regression are equivalent techniques. The coefficient of determination is the same for ANOVA as it is in an ordinary least squares model. Both methods find the "line of best fit" that minimizes the sum-of-squared residuals, and calculate the residual variance as a fraction of the total unconditional variance of the outcome.